# Sweave child rnw losing formatting

Tags: r, sweave, rstudio

I have managed to get a master.rnw include a child.rnw, however, I can maintain the formatting of the child document based on the preamble in the master.

Master.Rnw

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}%sets fonts across document
\geometry{a4paper,verbose,tmargin=7.5cm,bmargin=0.5cm,lmargin=0.5cm,rmargin=0.5cm}
\usepackage{tikz,Sweave,fancyvrb}
\title{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{/ header.png}}
  }
}
\leavevmode\newline
\SweaveInput{TCPQuote_CYB_short.Rnw}
\end{document}
```

Child.Rnw

```
% !Rnw root = Master.Rnw
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\LARGE
\color{blue}
\noindent
\begin{center}
\textbf\underline{ALL}
\end{center}
\leavevmode\newline
\fcolorbox{greylight}{greylight}{
   \parbox[c][2cm]{19.75cm}{
           \begin{tikzpicture}
              \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) 
              {\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm,keepaspectratio]{/why.png}};
              \node[align=left,{blue},font={\small\bfseries}] at (image.north) {Why?};
           \end{tikzpicture}
}}
```

Any idea how I include things such as the following to format the child?

```
\geometry{a4paper,verbose,tmargin=7.5cm,bmargin=0.5cm,lmargin=0.5cm,rmargin=0.5cm}
```

Answer (score 1):

IGNORE ME! solution was simply to add in

```
\small
```

for the font in my child.rnw!